# Featured questions not showing?

Tags: bug

It appears featured questions are not being listed on the featured tab, at least in Chrome.

I am on vacation at the moment and can not easily check other browsers.

[image]

Is this perhaps a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Your question was filtered from the home page due to its negative score - it still shows up here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured

We'll fix this issue so that all bountied questions still show on the home page's "featured" tab.

Comment: Is there any possibility of extending the bounty since it wasn't being displayed on the featured tab?

Comment: No, but I can refund the bounty and you can start it again.

Comment: That would be great, thank you.